# What is the algebraic role of the mathematical constant $\gamma$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, constants

Mathematical constants $\pi$, $e$, $i$ have a lot of algebraic roles. They appear as identity elements, idempotents, invariant elements etc against various operations and sets.

This is illustrated by the following identities:

$$(e^{i\pi})^2 = 1$$

$$i^4=1$$

$$(e^x)'=e^x$$

I wonder, what is the algebraic role of Euler-Mascheroni constant, $\gamma$?

Comment: Its $\gamma = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} 1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\cdots + \dfrac{1}{n} - \ln n$

Comment: I don't think you're going to find an illuminating algebraic role for $\gamma$, other than it's relation to harmonic numbers and the zeta function. This is probably because we have extremely limited knowledge about $\gamma$, unlike $i$,$e$,$\pi$.  Most places where $\gamma$ comes up are related to growth-rate corrections, like the usual harmonic sum, Merten's theorem and the blowup of $\zeta(s)$ at $s=1$.

Comment: @Alex R. well, but I thought I could miss something. My investigation so far was around the following: 1) $\gamma$ as natural integration constant when integrating $1/x$: natural integral of $1/x$ is $\gamma+\ln|x|$ 2) $\gamma$ as Cauchy mean value of some functions, such as $\Gamma(x)$ in poles, $\Gamma(0)=-\gamma$, which may have algebraic consequences following from functional equation for $\Gamma(x)$ 3) $\gamma$ as a twin of $\ln(4/\pi)$ (see wikipedia article)

Answer (score 0):

The constant manages to find its way to a number of important places like: infinite product, improper integral, definite integral of transcendental functions, power series, continued fractions, etc. To quote a few "identities" involved $\gamma$ we have:

1. $\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \left(\dfrac{1}{\ln x} + \dfrac{1}{1-x}\right)dx = \gamma$
2. $\displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty e^{-x}\ln^2 x dx = \gamma^2 + \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$
3. $\gamma = \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{\zeta(n)}{n}$

Comment: Can you show that these expansions demonstrate algebraic role of the constant? What the role is?

Comment: I see, so what? How this demonstrates the algebraic properties or $\gamma$? If I looked for analytic properties of expansions I could look ito Wikipedia. I am interested in alrgebraic role.

Comment: Okay. How is it related to algebra?

Comment: So you say, it has no algebraic role? Of what ring $\gamma$ is identity element or idempotent or against what operation it is invariant, etc?